# t.test error in R

Tags: r, apply

I have a dataframe with 6 columns. I tired performing a t.test on every row comparing columns 1 - 3 with columns 4 - 6 using the following command:

```
new.CL.10.ttest <- apply(new.CL, MARGIN = 1, function(m){
  t.test(x = m[1:3], y = m[4:6], alternative = 'two.sided')$p.value
})
```

I got the following error:

```
Error in if (stderr < 10 * .Machine$double.eps * max(abs(mx), abs(my))) stop("data are essentially constant") : 
  missing value where TRUE/FALSE needed In addition: Warning messages:
1: In mean.default(x) : argument is not numeric or logical: returning NA
2: In mean.default(y) : argument is not numeric or logical: returning NA
```

Could I please be advised on how I could resolve this issue?

Here is an example of data set (first 3 rows of a very long list). Numbers are actually floats but I rounded them off for simplicity:

```
col1    col2    col3   col4     col5    col6
80      100     96     96       93      97
50      45      47     45       54      39
53      44      52     45       68      47
```

Thanks

Comment: Yes this works but somewhere in my long list some data point is causing the problem. Is there a way to locate the data points causing the problem?

Comment: Why would comparing 3 numbers to another three numbers using a `t.test` deliver any useful information?

Comment: It's something I am working on. The background is not important here. I just need to get the pvalues for my dataset using t.test. I will p.adjust for multiple correction  later.

Comment: @user3302763  I posted a solution.  Could you try that on your original dataset?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose if there no variation in the dataset for a particular row

```
new.CL[2,] <- 45
```

Using your code, gives

```
#Error in t.test.default(x = m[1:3], y = m[4:6], alternative = "two.sided") : 
# data are essentially constant
```

I guess the error message is different because your original data rows are `floating numbers`.  Using the `rounded` dataset, a `logical` index can be created to drop the rows in the original/unrounded dataset.  One way to create an index is to check whether the first column is equal to all the columns in the dataset `(new.CL[,1]==new.CL)`.  Because of the `recycling`, what it does is check `elementwise` each column with the first column.  We get a logical matrix of `TRUE/FALSE`.  In this matrix, some rows have all `TRUE` i.e. the `data` is essentially constant here.  To eliminate those rows, do `rowSums` and check whether it is equal to `ncol(new.CL)`.

```
indx <- !rowSums(new.CL[,1]==new.CL)==ncol(new.CL)
```

Or

```
 indx <- !!rowSums(new.CL[,1]!=new.CL)

new.Cl1 <- Orig.CL[indx,]
```

#### data

```
new.CL <- structure(list(col1 = c(80L, 50L, 53L), col2 = c(100L, 45L, 44L
), col3 = c(96L, 47L, 52L), col4 = c(96L, 45L, 45L), col5 = c(93L, 
54L, 68L), col6 = c(97L, 39L, 47L)), .Names = c("col1", "col2", 
"col3", "col4", "col5", "col6"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-3L))
```

Comment: That did the trick. Thanks very much. Would you mind explaining the command: indx <- !rowSums(new.CL[,1]==new.CL)==ncol(new.CL). I do not fully understand it. I used dim() for new.Cl1 and my original list but did not see any change in the number of rows.